# start or call a non-admin app via admin-commandprompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wanted to ask you if it is possible to open a program (maybe editor.exe) with "start" or "call" command in windows-commandprompt, which is started via an administrator account, which then does not run managed via the administrator account.

That was the short question; here is something more comprehensible:
I started a command prompt ("script.bat") with right mouse button "as admin", here i type admin user and password (user account: admin01).
In the task manager, I see that the program "cmd.exe" is associated with the "admin01". So far so good.
Now I want to start another app (maybe editor.exe) with "start" or "call" command in this active command prompt ("script.bat"); however, in the task manager i should not have "admin01" as user next to the program that has just been started.I want the corresponding user to be "theLocalActiveRegisteredUser".

Do you know how I can do this?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to unelevate a program. Elevation is a one way street. Programs started by an elevated program are elevated.

The main indirect way to start an unelevated program is to use task scheduler and demand run the TS task (this is what explorer does to always start unelevated).

EG

```
schtasks /run /I /tn "\MyTaskThatStartsAProgram"
```

Comment: Good answer, but remove the "There is no way to unelevate a program" as it's not true.